# How to parse information from aviasales.com

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to collect 10 best prices from the air tickets aggregator - http://www.aviasales.com.

For example, we will find 10 cheapest prices for Moscow-Barcelona flight on 6 August. The concrete URL is http://www.aviasales.com/flights/MOW0608BCN1.
As you know, any aggregator spends several seconds performing the search and then show the cheapest offers. Therefore, the problem consists in the fact that data, which I can scrape at the initial point of page start loading, doesn't have the required information. It appears only 30 seconds after page starts downloading.

According to my opinion, the easiest way to solve the problem is some kind of timer. But the **scraper** in my code opens the page again, from zero. And, therefore, collect data without prices. What can I do in this situation?

I enclose my code below (the first best price):

```
import requests, bs4
import time
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://www.aviasales.com/flights/MOW0608BCN1')
time.sleep(30)
url=requests.get('http://www.aviasales.com/flights/MOW0608BCN1')
b=bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")
price_string=b.select('currency_font currency_font-usd')
price=price_string[0].getText()
print(price)
```

Required data number:
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo?album_id=5263636965&photo_id=500604214523

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the website it's not a reliable solution in long term perspective e.g. HTML markup of a page could be changed on the next release.

You could use API (http://www.aviasales.ru/API) for getting required information.

If you want to implement parsing for some reason. I'd recommend to check out Selenium and PhantomJS (or other headless browser). Waits commands (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) will help you to detect presence of CSS class on a page.